# Installing requirements.txt on heroku runs error

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I am deploying an application using heroku. In the python code I am using a NLP library called **spacy**.
I already deployed the app without any installed library, working perfectly.

I added the library in the requirements.txt of the app:

[image]

In my cmd, at the time of deployment I am using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, it runs an error:

[image]

intentionally avoided writing the code because of the sizeI also installed Microsoft C++ Build Tools and restarted cmd, but now it runs additional errors.

This is a screenshot of the files I am uploading:

[image]

Is there a way I can install the libraries remotely? I would like to avoid countless installations. Given the red code, am I doing something wrong or am I just missing packages?

(intentionally avoided writing the code because of the size)

Answer (score 0):

That is a local error on your Windows machine, that should not occur on Heroku. The Heroku build pack should automatically install dependencies if you put requirements.txt at root. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

For fixing your local error, you need to install the C++ build tools as per the error message.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the files I am trying to upload. I already added requirements.txt, but always run error. Should I add anything else? I am not interested in installing anything locally, only uploading to Heroku.

Comment: I'd suggest using 'pip freeze > requirements.txt' to save all dependencies. What error do you get when you deploy to Heroku?

Comment: I also tried with pip freeze > requirements.txt. In the app.py I use import spacy. After checking the logs it shows that spacy is not recognized.

Comment: You could try and use the latest version of spacy to see if that changes anything. You could also use Heroku Exec to interrogate the runtime to see what is going on.